# BigQuery seems to be deleting my data piped from Segment every two months

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I use Data Studio for visualizations and graphs of my stripe data.

I use Segment to pipe data from Stripe to BigQuery. It loaded historical data of over a year and continually allowed this data to stay in the warehouse. Then, without warning I noticed one day that the data before May of this year was gone. I contacted Segment and they said it wasn't them.

Of course that was not a satisfactory answer. BigQuery data is not going to just delete its self. I decided it must be a fluke and just reconnected the pipe.

Sure enough I checked today and May and June are gone and all that remains is end of June thru today.

I want to figure out what is causing this. The data is deleting its self. Ive tried manual sql queries and they pull up nothing either. Segment claims it isnt them. But it isn't me. I'm not sure what to do.

Please help. I hate dealing with data loss and I'm not excited about having to import the data by CSV.. especially if it will just delete its self too.

Comment: BigQuery does allow you to set table expiration. I think that can happen at the table-level and the dataset-level.  Can you check your configurations to see if that is enabled?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage

Comment: @rtenha please add this as an answer because, after researching your suggestion, I found that the table is partitioned and there is a PARTITION expiration set to 60 days. Hoping this is the culprit! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery does allow you to set table expiration. I think that can happen at the table-level and the dataset-level. Can you check your configurations to see if that is enabled? [cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage](http://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage)